# How to convert array into variables

Tags: php

I want to hold each value of my array in variable and print out the values according to their variable names.

My code

```
$arr = "PRE;OS0101001;123456;ATAKUMOSA EAST;IWARA;TOWN HALL IWARA;Yes;NGNOS10001;1000;5;Yes;10234OS;Yes;785;;2018-08-26 06:59:35";

$delimiter = array(",",".","'","\"","|","\\","/",";",":");
$replace = str_replace($delimiter, $delimiter[0], $arr);
$explode = explode($delimiter[0], $replace);
print_r($explode);
```

Which gives this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PRE
    [1] => OS0101001
    [2] => 123456
    [3] => ATAKUMOSA EAST
    [4] => IWARA
    [5] => TOWN HALL IWARA
    [6] => Yes
    [7] => NGNOS10001
    [8] => 1000
    [9] => 5
    [10] => Yes
    [11] => 10234OS
    [12] => Yes
    [13] => 785
    [14] => 
    [15] => 2018-08-26 06
    [16] => 59
    [17] => 35
)
```

And I want to print it in this format

```
   $officer_id = $array[1];
    $userpassword = $array[2];
```

etc..

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: So you're trying to output a result that is PHP code? Why not just use serialize? There's also var_export.

Comment: @Ultimater, yes I am. If I know how to do that I won't have asked. Could you show me please?

Comment: Whats wrong with `echo "\$officer_id = ".$array[1].PHP_EOL;` etc  or clarify further...

Comment: If this is from a CSV file (that's what it looks like), which contains a header, then rather build an associative array (via `array_combine`) rather than a dozen local variables. // The purpose of delimiter rewriting is also completely unclear.

Comment: @mario I agree with the assoc array idea - but was not sure if her $arr was a once off in which case hard coding maybe be easier, given the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your string looks like a csv line you can use `str_getcsv` to parse it even easier.

```
$array = str_getcsv($arr,";","");
```

You can always use `list` to assign your explode results to individual variables.

```
list( ,$officer_id, $password, $sthg, $alsoSthg ) = explode($delimiter[0], $replace);
```

or if you have used the `str_getcsv`

```
 list( ,$officer_id, $password, $sthg, $alsoSthg ) = $array;
```

you can increase the number of variables in `list` as long as you're sure that it has a correspondence in the array. Please note that I intentionally left the first parameter in `list` blank, to show that you can leave that (or any other) parameter empty, if you don't want to assign it to a variable. [More info on list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: it is an incoming sms from twilio. Can I still use  str_getcsv for it?

Comment: the key here is **looks like** so yes you can parse that line, with `str_getcsv`.